# Faking Post Request with PHP Curl - Rejection

Tags: php, reverse-engineering

I am trying to build a script that posts information into the [RoyalMail tracking system](http://track2.royalmail.com/portal/rm/track) and extracts the output.

What I currently have is getting an error from their server - see the link, somehow it is detecting that I am not using their website as per normal and throwing me an error.

Things I think I have taken into account:

- Using an exact copy of their form by parsing it beforehand (the post parameters)
- Saving the cookies between each request
- Accepting redirect headers
- Providing a refer header that is actually valid (the previously visited page)

Does anyone know anything else I need to check or can figure out what I am doing wrong?

A full copy of the source is at EDIT: please see my answer below

Comment: _I am getting an error from their server_ - what error are you getting? Edit: aha, it is in your second link.

Comment: I was getting an error but needed to follow their redirects!

Comment: @pez - So you managed to solve this?

Comment: Nope unfortunately now I have the Sorry... An error has occurred. Page instead of the 301 redirect page. Still no idea what's causing the system to realise it's not a real user yet!

Comment: Keep in mind that you are in fact attempting to `"hack"` a government owned postal service.  It would be safe to assume that they have specific methods enabled to prevent exactly what you are trying to do... Another thing to take into consideration is the frequency that you are pinging their service... If your are sending too many requests too fast, your IP might have been already blacklisted as a suspect for flooding attacks...

Comment: Are you aware you can use this URL without using `post`? http://www.royalmail.com/track-trace?trackNumber=ZW791944749GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now fixed it, the problem was with PHP curl and following redirects, it seems that it doesn't always post the request data and sends a GET request when following.

To deal with this I disabled curl follow location with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);` and then built a follow location system myself that works recursively. Essentially it extracts the location header from the response, checks for a 301 or a 302 and then runs the method again as required.

This means the information will definitely be POSTED again.

I also improved the user agent string, simply copying my current one on the basis it won't be blocked for a long while as in 2012 it is in active use!

Here is a final copy of the curl class (in case the link dies - been down voted for that in the past) which is working:

```
/**
 * Make a curl request respecting redirects
 * Also supports posts
 */
class pegCurlRequest {
  private $url, $postFields = array(), $referer = NULL, $timeout = 3;
  private $debug = false, $postString = "";
  private $curlInfo = array();
  private $content = "";
  private $response_meta_info = array();

  static $cookie;

  function __construct($url, $postFields = array(), $referer = NULL, $timeout = 3) {
    $this->setUrl($url);
    $this->setPost($postFields);
    $this->setReferer($referer);
    $this->setTimeout($timeout);
    if(empty(self::$cookie)) self::$cookie = tempnam("/tmp", "pegCurlRequest"); //one time cookie
  }

  function setUrl($url) {
    $this->url = $url;
  }

  function setTimeout($timeout) {
    $this->timeout = $timeout;
  }

  function setPost($postFields) {
    if(is_array($postFields)) {
      $this->postFields = $postFields;
    }
    $this->updatePostString();
  }

  function updatePostString() {
    //Cope with posting
    $this->postString = "";
    if(!empty($this->postFields)) {
      foreach($this->postFields as $key=>$value) { $this->postString .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
      $this->postString= rtrim($this->postString,'&'); //Trim off the waste
    }   
  }

  function setReferer($referer) {
    //Set a referee either specified or based on the url
    $this->referer = $referer;
  }

  function debugInfo() {
    //Debug
    if($this->debug) {
      echo "<table><tr><td colspan='2'><b><u>Pre Curl Request</b><u></td></tr>";
      echo "<tr><td><b>URL: </b></td><td>{$this->url}</td></tr>";
      if(!empty(self::$cookie)) echo "<tr><td><b>Cookie String: </b></td><td>".self::$cookie."</td></tr>";
      if(!empty($this->referer)) echo "<tr><td><b>Referer: </b></td><td>".$this->referer."</td></tr>";
      if(!empty($this->postString)) echo "<tr><td><b>Post String: </b></td><td>".$this->postString."</td></tr>";

      if(!empty($this->postFields)) {
        echo "<tr><td><b>Post Values:</b></td><td><table>";
        foreach($this->postFields as $key=>$value)
          echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>$value</td></tr>";
        echo "</table>";
      }
      echo "</td></tr></table><br />\n"; 
    } 
  }

  function debugFurtherInfo() {
    //Debug
    if($this->debug) {
      echo "<table><tr><td colspan='2'><b><u>Post Curl Request</b><u></td></tr>";
      echo "<tr><td><b>URL: </b></td><td>{$this->url}</td></tr>";
      if(!empty($this->referer)) echo "<tr><td><b>Referer: </b></td><td>".$this->referer."</td></tr>";
      if(!empty($this->curlInfo)) {
        echo "<tr><td><b>Curl Info:</b></td><td><table>";
        foreach($this->curlInfo as $key=>$value)
          echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>$value</td></tr>";
        echo "</table>";
      }
      echo "</td></tr></table><br />\n"; 
    } 
  }

  /**
   * Make the actual request
   */
  function makeRequest($url=NULL) {
    //Shorthand request
    if(!is_null($url))
      $this->setUrl($url);

    //Output debug info
    $this->debugInfo();

    //Using a shared cookie
    $cookie = self::$cookie;

    //Setting up the starting information
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.11 Safari/536.11" );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");

     //register a callback function which will process the headers
    //this assumes your code is into a class method, and uses $this->readHeader as the callback //function
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array(&$this,'readHeader'));

    //Some servers (like Lighttpd) will not process the curl request without this header and will return error code 417 instead. 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Expect:"));

    //Referer
    if(empty($this->referer)) {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, dirname($this->url));
    } else {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $this->referer);
    }

    //Posts
    if(!empty($this->postFields)) {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->postString);
    }

    //Redirects, transfers and timeouts
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

    //Debug
    if($this->debug) {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); // logging stuffs
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // enable tracking
    }

    //Get the content and the header info
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = curl_getinfo($ch);

    //get the default response headers
    $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);

    //add the headers from the custom headers callback function
    $this->response_meta_info = array_merge($headers, $this->response_meta_info);

    curl_close($ch); //be nice

    //Curl info
    $this->curlInfo = $response;

    //Output debug info
    $this->debugFurtherInfo();

    //Are we being redirected?
    if ($response['http_code'] == 301 || $response['http_code'] == 302) {
      $location = $this->getHeaderLocation();
      if(!empty($location)) { //the location exists
        $this->setReferer($this->getTrueUrl()); //update referer
        return $this->makeRequest($location); //recurse to location
      }
    } 
    //Is there a javascript redirect on the page?
    elseif (preg_match("/window\.location\.replace\('(.*)'\)/i", $content, $value) ||
      preg_match("/window\.location\=\"(.*)\"/i", $content, $value)) {
      $this->setReferer($this->getTrueUrl()); //update referer
      return $this->makeRequest($value[1]); //recursion
    } else {
      $this->content = $content; //set the content - final page
    }
  }

  /**
   * Get the url after any redirection
   */
  function getTrueUrl() {
    return $this->curlInfo['url'];
  }

  function __toString() {
    return $this->content;
  }

  /**
   * CURL callback function for reading and processing headers
   * Override this for your needs
   * 
   * @param object $ch
   * @param string $header
   * @return integer
   */
  private function readHeader($ch, $header) {
      //This is run for every header, use ifs to grab and add
      $location = $this->extractCustomHeader('Location: ', '\n', $header);
      if ($location) {
          $this->response_meta_info['location'] = trim($location);
      }
      return strlen($header);
  }

  private function extractCustomHeader($start,$end,$header) {
      $pattern = '/'. $start .'(.*?)'. $end .'/';
      if (preg_match($pattern, $header, $result)) {
          return $result[1];
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  }

  function getHeaders() {
      return $this->response_meta_info;
  }

  function getHeaderLocation() {
      return $this->response_meta_info['location'];
  }
}
```

Comment: The code is less interesting than the actual solution.  could you please explain your solution in more detail as opposed to simply dumping your whole script here?

Comment: Added above with further detail for you

Answer (score 2):

Websites usually use 2 ways to detect if you are a human or a bot: HTTP REFERER and USER AGENT. I suggest you use Curl it specified user agent and referer (replace 'http://something/' with real URL of a page you would normally visit before navigating to the url you want to download with PHP):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://track2.royalmail.com/portal/rm/track';
$html = file_get_contents2($url, '');


$post['_dyncharset'] = 'ISO-8859-1';

$post['trackConsigniaPage'] = 'track';

$post['/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.searchCompleteUrl'] = '/portal/rm/trackresults?catId=22700601&pageId=trt_rmresultspage';
$post['_D:/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.searchCompleteUrl'] = ''; 
$post['/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.invalidInputUrl'] = '/portal/rm/trackresults?catId=22700601&pageId=trt_rmresultspage&keyname=track_blank';
$post['_D:/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.invalidInputUrl'] = '';
$post['/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.searchBusyUrl'] = '/portal/rm/trackresults?catId=22700601&pageId=trt_busypage&keyname=3E_track';
$post['_D:/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.searchBusyUrl'] = ''; 
$post['/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.searchWaitUrl'] = '/portal/rm/trackresults?catId=22700601&timeout=true&pageId=trt_timeoutpage&keyname=3E_track';
$post['_D:/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.searchWaitUrl'] = ''; 
$post['/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.keyname'] = '3E_track';
$post['_D:/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.keyname'] = ''; 
$post['/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.previousTrackingNumber'] = '';
$post['_D:/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.previousTrackingNumber'] = ''; 
$post['/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.trackingNumber'] = 'ZW791944749GB';
$post['_D:/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.trackingNumber'] = ''; 
$post['/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.track.x'] = '50';
$post['/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.track.y'] = '14';
$post['_D:/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.track'] = ''; 
$post['/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.day'] = '19';
$post['_D:/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.day'] = ''; 
$post['/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.month'] = '5';
$post['_D:/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.month'] = '';
$post['/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.year'] = '2012';
$post['_D:/rmg/track/RMTrackFormHandler.value.year'] = ''; 
$post['_DARGS'] = '/portal/rmgroup/apps/templates/html/rm/rmTrackResultPage.jsp';

$url2 = 'http://track2.royalmail.com/portal/rm?_DARGS=/portal/rmgroup/apps/templates/html/rm/rmTrackAndTraceForm.jsp';
$html2 = file_get_contents2($url2, $url, $post);

echo $html2;

function file_get_contents2($address, $referer, $post = false)
{   
    $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1"; 

    $c = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $address);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);     
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    if ($post)
    {
        $postF = http_build_query($post);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postF);    
    }

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    //curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    if (!$data = curl_exec($c)) 
    {
        return false; 
    } 

    return $data;
}
```

The above updated code returned me:

```
Item ZW791944749GB was posted at 1 High Street RG17 9TJ on 19/05/12 and is being progressed through our network for delivery.
```

So it seems it works.

Comment: If you check my code you'll see I am already doing this, perhaps I should have made it clearer!

Comment: Ok, but you use "Firefox/0.10.1" as user agent. They can check version number and ban too old browsers. Try higher number. Http header 301 is for redirects- where does it redirect you to? Also please save into a file what exactly you get from them and post the file somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, you **are** talking about the Royal Mail.  So I'm not sure if this simple little trick would trip them up...

But what you *could* try is spoofing your user agent with a quick `ini_set()` -

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 1660.57.0) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.46 Safari/535.19'
```

That's an Ubuntu chrome user agent string.

The `cURL` user agent string would look quite different.  For example:

```
curl/7.15.5 (i686-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
```

It's a long shot - but they might be rejecting requests that are not originating from recognized browsers.

Comment: If you check the code you will see I am using: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );

Comment: @PezCuckow if you would like people to view the code, you should really paste it into your question.

Comment: I marked you as correct as you pointed me in the right direction early on, thought it wasn't what actually fixed it! I have made an answer with a full copy of the solution.

Comment: If it is not the solution, and you can provide the solution that you used - you should mark your own answer as the accepted one... Give me an upvote if you feel I helped though... ;)